# Find the extension of a filename in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on the file upload portion of a Rails app.  Different types of files are handled differently by the app.

I want to make a whitelist of certain file extensions to check the uploaded files against to see where they should go.  All of the file names are strings.

I need a way to check only the extension part of the file name string.  The file names are all in the format of "some_file_name.some_extension".

Answer (score 187, accepted):

```
irb(main):002:0> accepted_formats = [".txt", ".pdf"]
=> [".txt", ".pdf"]
irb(main):003:0> File.extname("example.pdf") # get the extension
=> ".pdf"
irb(main):004:0> accepted_formats.include? File.extname("example.pdf")
=> true
irb(main):005:0> accepted_formats.include? File.extname("example.txt")
=> true
irb(main):006:0> accepted_formats.include? File.extname("example.png")
=> false
```

Comment: How about `"file_with_no_extension".split('.').last`?

Comment: It's unfortunate this doesn't work for multi-period suffixes such as `tar.gz`, `tar.bz2`.

Comment: @KomodoDave nothing works for multi-period suffixes, except an heuristic (thus error prone) database of extensions.

Comment: You would want to do `File.extname("example.png").downcase` to ensure that the extension is not in all caps

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 Unless you choose to include anything after the first dot... but then people create file names with dots, so yeah, either way is error prone, agreed on that.

Answer (score 91):

Use `extname` method from File class

```
File.extname("test.rb")         #=> ".rb"
```

Also you may need `basename` method

```
File.basename("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb", ".rb")   #=> "ruby"
```

Answer (score 18):

Quite old topic but here is the way to get rid of extension separator dot and possible trailing spaces:

```
File.extname(path).strip.downcase[1..-1]
```

Examples:

```
File.extname(".test").strip.downcase[1..-1]       # => nil
File.extname(".test.").strip.downcase[1..-1]      # => nil
File.extname(".test.pdf").strip.downcase[1..-1]   # => "pdf"
File.extname(".test.pdf ").strip.downcase[1..-1]  # => "pdf"
```

Answer (score 7):

I my opinion it would be easier to do this to get rid of the extension separator.

```
File.extname(path).delete('.')
```

Comment: I use `File.extname(path).delete_prefix(".")` – I feel it communicates intent better (only prefixed, only one) though AFAIK there's no practical difference – `File.extname("foo.bar.baz")` will just give `".baz"`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach, using `delete_suffix` and `delete_prefix`. This is easier to read, IMO.

```rb
filename = 'path/to/file.ext'
file_name_only = File.basename(filename).delete_suffix(File.extname(filename))
file_ext = File.extname(filename).delete_prefix '.'
file_path = File.dirname(filename)
new_name = "#{file_path}/#{file_name_only}_blahblah.#{file_ext}"
```

In IRB:

```rb
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> filename = 'path/to/file.ext'
=> "path/to/file.ext"
irb(main):002:0> file_name_only = File.basename(filename).delete_suffix(File.extname(filename))
=> "file"
irb(main):003:0> file_ext = File.extname(filename).delete_prefix '.'
=> "ext"
irb(main):004:0> file_path = File.dirname(filename)
=> "path/to"
irb(main):005:0> new_name = "#{file_path}/#{file_name_only}_blahblah.#{file_ext}"
=> "path/to/file_blahblah.ext"
irb(main):006:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

This post answered my question, however my use case was the opposite. I wanted to find the name of the file without the extension. I found the file name with `File.basename`, then combined `File.extname` with `gsub` to remove the `.md` like so:

```rb
@file = '/path/to/my-file-name.md' 
File.basename(@file).gsub(File.extname(@file),'')

# => 'my-file-name'
```