# Display only message without attribute in a model with belongs to other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display a message without attribute on a form.
I have two classes,  issue_attachment and issue.

No model issue_attachment, I have a method that checks if a file ends with exe,.com.., among others, if yes, it returns an error message.

The problem is that I do not want the error message is complete. But I can not do this. I've tried every variation of ":base" and nothing works.

I did some tests and put the verification method in class issue and using ":base" and it work.

But I need the validate method: suspitious_attachment issue_attachment stay in class.

```
issue.rb

has_many :attachments, class_name: 'IssueAttachment', dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
```

issue_attachment.rb

```
validate :suspitious_attachment

private

def suspitious_attachment
  if ends_with? '.bat', '.com', '.exe', '.src', '.cmd'
    errors.add(:attachment, I18n.t('errors.messages.suspitious_attachment', :value =>   attachment.path[-4..-1]))
  end
end

def ends_with?(*args)
  args.each do |arg|
    return true if attachment.path.ends_with? arg
  end
  false
  end  
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <%= image_tag 'icons/required.png', :alt => '*' %><%= t('labels.attachments') %>
    <div class="input">
      <div class="inputs-list">
        <%= f.fields_for :attachments do |builder| %>
          <%= render 'attachment_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add t('actions.add_another_attachment'), :attachments, :class => 'icon-attach' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know the error?

My english is very bad? :PP

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your errors are, but I think you have a problem with the end_with method.

As suggested by the answers to another questions, there are easy Ruby ways to find the extension and check it against a list of allowed types. Please see this one:
[Find the extension of a filename in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082444/find-the-extension-of-a-filename-in-ruby)

I would test that you have the correct files names in your suspitious_attachment method then employ a similar method to those described in the answers above.

Hope this helps